# Using Mongoose JS to get array of pointer values for document, and expand return

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What I am trying to do is the following.

I have objects that could live in multiple documents, and although I am not sure if this is best practice, I am using their ObjectId as pointers.

Document A

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "51a02dade4b02780aeee5ab7"
},
"title": "My Document A",
"artifacts": [
    "51a81d8ee4b084336fea2d33",
    "asdfsdfe4b084336fea2d33"
]
```

}

Document B

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "51a02dade4b02780aeee5ab7"
},
"title": "My Document A",
"artifacts": [
    "51a81d8ee4b084336fea2d33",
    "123454b084336fea2d33"
]
```

}

The individual artifact looks something like. If this artifact changes then there is no need to update the documents that it lives in:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51a81d8ee4b084336fea2d33"
    },
    "title": "Artifact A",
    "media": {
        "player": "video",
        "source": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12334456"
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do, is get an expanded list of all the artifacts shown in either doc A or doc B in an array something like:

```
[{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "51a81d8ee4b084336fea2d33"
        },
        "title": "Artifact A",
        "media": {
            "player": "video",
            "source": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12334456"
        }
    },
{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "123455e4b084336fea2d33"
        },
        "title": "Artifact B",
        "media": {
            "player": "video",
            "source": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12334456"
        }
    }]
```

The way I have done it in the past is by POSTing from client a list of Ids and then using

```
{_id: { $in: userQuestArray} }
```

but if i am constantly posting back to node from the client it seems a bit inefficient. Especially if the array I am posting is hundreds of items long.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what your question is. MongoDb doesn't have functionality to return "linked" documents in a single query. Your technique is a common solution. Some language drivers have a way of making it seem like it does, but it's only an illusion of something more efficient.

Comment: I think the mongoose `populate` feature might solve your problem. It provides functions in mongoose to link documents, using mongoose Schema, and tools that help update/query using those relationships between documents.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mongoose provide you a feature population which exactly does the same thing you are looking for http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html. In your case what you need to do is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, Schema = mongoose.Schema

var tempSchema = Schema({    
title    : String,   
artifacts : [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Artifacts' }]
});

var artifactsSchema = Schema({    
title    : String,   
media : { player: String, source: String, }
});

var tempModel  = mongoose.model('Temp', tempSchema);
var artifactsModel = mongoose.model('Artifacts', artifactsSchema);
```

Now whenever artifacts documents gets created you need to push that in respective temp dcoument artifacts array as shown in mongoose documentation. You can retrive it like that

```
tempModel
    .find(query)
    .populate('artifacts')
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        if (err)
            console.log(err);

        console.log(results);
    })
 //results contains data in form shown below
 [{
   "_id": {
     "$oid": "51a02dade4b02780aeee5ab7"
    },
   "title": "My Document A",
   "artifacts": [{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "51a81d8ee4b084336fea2d33"
    },
    "title": "Artifact A",
    "media": {
        "player": "video",
        "source": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12334456"
    }
   },
   {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "123455e4b084336fea2d33"
    },
    "title": "Artifact B",
    "media": {
        "player": "video",
        "source": "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12334456"
    }
   }]
 }]
```